# Fill missing date gaps in SQL query on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a table `messages` that  looks like:

| status | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sent | timestamp | timestamp |
| queued | timestamp | timestamp |
| failed | timestamp | timestamp |

I want a query that outputs values in a way that is easy to chart, I came up with this query:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', created_at) as hour_created, count(created_at), status 
FROM messages 
WHERE created_at >= current_timestamp - interval '1 day' 
GROUP BY (status, hour_created)
```

That query outputs the following:

| hour_created | count | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-11 08:00:00-04 | 10 | sent |
| 2021-10-11 09:00:00-04 | 95 | queued |
| 2021-10-11 10:00:00-04 | 174 | sent |
| 2021-10-11 12:00:00-04 | 1 | sent |
| 2021-10-11 13:00:00-04 | 1 | queued |
| 2021-10-11 13:00:00-04 | 2 | sent |
| 2021-10-11 14:00:00-04 | 1 | sent |
| 2021-10-11 18:00:00-04 | 2 | sent |

Notice the gaps in the hours, I want to fill those with every possible status (queued, failed and sent) and a zero

Answer (score 0):

you can use generate series :

```
select date_trunc('hour', created_at) as hour_created, count(created_at), status 
from generate_series(date_trunc('hour',current_timestamp) - interval '1 day' ,date_trunc('hour',current_timestamp), '1 hour') intervals (cdate)
cross join (select * from (values ('failed'),('queued'),('sent')) s (status)) statuses
join messages t
on t.status = statuses.status
and t.created_at = intervals.cdate
WHERE created_at >= current_timestamp - interval '1 day' 
GROUP BY statuses.status, intervals.cdate
```

Comment: Suggestion: `SELECT <the date/hour expression from series> AS series_hour, ... LEFT JOIN messages t` and `GROUP BY statuses, series_hour`.  This should avoid dropping the missing cases, and also selecting nulls from the missing message groups.